# python pandas join dataframes on both axis (merge in all directions)

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I don't know the relevant keyword for the problem I am facing. I am reading in a series of dataframes and attempting to join each of them into a single large dataframe. The dfs are time series data and some of them need to be appended vertically and some need to be appended horizontally. There are several thousand but this example captures the problem.

The problem is I can't find a pandas function that can handle merging in both directions without prior knowledge of what is being read in.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["01-01-2000","02-01-2000","03-01-2000","04-01-2000","05-01-2000"] ,
                   'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [2.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000","07-01-2000","08-01-2000","09-01-2000","10-01-2000"] ,
                   'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.1, 0.1, 3.1, 4.0, 0]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000","07-01-2000","08-01-2000","09-01-2000","10-01-2000"] ,
                   'TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.6, 0.7, 5.1, 1.0, 2.0]})  

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]

merged_df = pd.DataFrame()

for df in df_list:
    merged_df = merged_df.merge(df, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(merged_df)

GMT_date_x  LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)_x  GMT_date_y  LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)_y    GMT_date  TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)
0  01-01-2000                                2.2  06-01-2000                                0.1  06-01-2000                              0.6
1  02-01-2000                                0.0  07-01-2000                                0.1  07-01-2000                              0.7
2  03-01-2000                                0.2  08-01-2000                                3.1  08-01-2000                              5.1
3  04-01-2000                                0.4  09-01-2000                                4.0  09-01-2000                              1.0
4  05-01-2000                                0.0  10-01-2000                                0.0  10-01-2000                              2.0
```

As you can see the columns have been allocated a new column for each df, I wanted them in a single column. I've also tried the following merge:

```
merged_df  = pd.concat([merged_df , df], sort=True)
```

which produces:

```
     GMT_date  LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)  TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)
0  01-01-2000                              2.2                              NaN
1  02-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN
2  03-01-2000                              0.2                              NaN
3  04-01-2000                              0.4                              NaN
4  05-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN
0  06-01-2000                              0.1                              NaN
1  07-01-2000                              0.1                              NaN
2  08-01-2000                              3.1                              NaN
3  09-01-2000                              4.0                              NaN
4  10-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN
0  06-01-2000                              NaN                              0.6
1  07-01-2000                              NaN                              0.7
2  08-01-2000                              NaN                              5.1
3  09-01-2000                              NaN                              1.0
4  10-01-2000                              NaN                              2.0
```

Now the dates are in a single columns which I wanted but there are duplicates in the date column. I tried:

```
merged_df = merged_df.join(df)
```

which throws an error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['GMT_date', 'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)'], dtype='object')
```

I've also tried setting the index to GMT_date:

```
for df in df_list:
    df = df.set_index('GMT_date')
    merged_df = pd.concat([merged_df, df], axis=1)
print(merged_df)

            LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)  LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)  TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)
01-01-2000                              2.2                              NaN                              NaN
02-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN                              NaN
03-01-2000                              0.2                              NaN                              NaN
04-01-2000                              0.4                              NaN                              NaN
05-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN                              NaN
06-01-2000                              NaN                              0.1                              0.6
07-01-2000                              NaN                              0.1                              0.7
08-01-2000                              NaN                              3.1                              5.1
09-01-2000                              NaN                              4.0                              1.0
10-01-2000                              NaN                              0.0                              2.0
```

This resolves the date into a single column and there are no duplicate dates but now I have data spread into 2 columns with the same name?

I must be missing a simple function or argument which solves merging in both directions in a single line?

I tried looking at: pd.merge_asof but it only seems to return dates which are shared between 2 dfs.

I'm hoping there is a simple fix? It feel like instead of 'how' : {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’} I need an option for 'all' in merge.

Comment: I can be wrong, but If I understood you correctly here can be no simple solution. pd.concat is always used to join vertically and merge is used for horizontal join.

Comment: concat can join horizontally.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to join vertically and horizontally in one line. Another way to think of it is essentially 'populating' a df and expanding it (if necessary) at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another solution, after concatenating all dataframes merge duplicate columns with groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["01-01-2000", "02-01-2000", "03-01-2000", "04-01-2000", "05-01-2000"],
                    'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [2.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000", "07-01-2000", "08-01-2000", "09-01-2000", "10-01-2000"],
                    'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.1, 0.1, 3.1, 4.0, 0]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000", "07-01-2000", "08-01-2000", "09-01-2000", "10-01-2000"],
                    'TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.6, 0.7, 5.1, 1.0, 2.0]})

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
merged_df = pd.DataFrame()

for df in df_list:
    df = df.set_index('GMT_date')

    merged_df = pd.concat([merged_df, df], axis=1)

merged_df = merged_df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(np.max)

print(merged_df)
```

output:

```
            LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)  TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)
01-01-2000                              2.2                              NaN
02-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN
03-01-2000                              0.2                              NaN
04-01-2000                              0.4                              NaN
05-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN
06-01-2000                              0.1                              0.6
07-01-2000                              0.1                              0.7
08-01-2000                              3.1                              5.1
09-01-2000                              4.0                              1.0
10-01-2000                              0.0                              2.0
```

---

you can use

```
merged_df = merged_df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(np.max if np.nan else sum) # if there is `Nan` then it will take `np.max` else take sum of values
```

Comment: I've just run this over a bigger set of test data and it seems to work, would you mind to just explain the logic a bit for my understanding so I can check the output a bit more comprehensively? particularly the .agg(np.max) part? Is this checking for the presence of a number and updating with the highest value?

Comment: yes you have to do it because of nan values, nan is float negative, so it will take other then the nan value

Comment: if you take sum then it will replace nan with zero, i am sure you don't want that

Comment: Cool, I think this works! I wouldn't have found this on my own so very much appreciated! I'm a little worried about the operation time over the full dataset but it does the job at least! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

first concat all dataframe which has `LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_` and 
concat all df that has `TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)` then use merge

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["01-01-2000", "02-01-2000", "03-01-2000", "04-01-2000", "05-01-2000"],
                    'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [2.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000", "07-01-2000", "08-01-2000", "09-01-2000", "10-01-2000"],
                    'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.1, 0.1, 3.1, 4.0, 0]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000", "07-01-2000", "08-01-2000", "09-01-2000", "10-01-2000"],
                    'TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.6, 0.7, 5.1, 1.0, 2.0]})
# merge_df = pd.DataFrame()

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(new_df)
merge_df = pd.merge(new_df, df3, how='left')
print(merge_df)
```

**output:**

```
     GMT_date  LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)  TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)
0  01-01-2000                              2.2                              NaN
1  02-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN
2  03-01-2000                              0.2                              NaN
3  04-01-2000                              0.4                              NaN
4  05-01-2000                              0.0                              NaN
5  06-01-2000                              0.1                              0.6
6  07-01-2000                              0.1                              0.7
7  08-01-2000                              3.1                              5.1
8  09-01-2000                              4.0                              1.0
9  10-01-2000                              0.0                              2.0
```

---

for example you have this kind of df

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["01-01-2000", "02-01-2000", "03-01-2000", "04-01-2000", "05-01-2000"],
                    'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [2.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000", "07-01-2000", "08-01-2000", "09-01-2000", "10-01-2000"],
                    'LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.1, 0.1, 3.1, 4.0, 0]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["06-01-2000", "07-01-2000", "08-01-2000", "09-01-2000", "10-01-2000"],
                    'TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.6, 0.7, 5.1, 1.0, 2.0]})

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'GMT_date': ["01-01-2000", "02-01-2000", "03-01-2000", "04-01-2000", "05-01-2000"],
                    'TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)': [0.6, 0.7, 5.1, 1.0, 2.0]})
# merge_df = pd.DataFrame()
# df1.set_index('GMT_date')

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
new_df2 = pd.concat([df3, df4])

print(new_df)
merge_df = pd.merge(new_df, new_df2, how='left')
print(merge_df)
```

**output:**

```
     GMT_date  LOWI_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)  TGPY_Precipitation_24_Hour_(mm)
0  01-01-2000                              2.2                              0.6
1  02-01-2000                              0.0                              0.7
2  03-01-2000                              0.2                              5.1
3  04-01-2000                              0.4                              1.0
4  05-01-2000                              0.0                              2.0
5  06-01-2000                              0.1                              0.6
6  07-01-2000                              0.1                              0.7
7  08-01-2000                              3.1                              5.1
8  09-01-2000                              4.0                              1.0
9  10-01-2000                              0.0                              2.0
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however there are several thousand of these df's and they don't all have the same colnames, some do, some don't and I can't be sure of the order until i read them in and process them. Its possible you may be right though - I may have to write and if/else to detect if a horizontal or vertical join is needed before doing the join. Many thanks

Comment: you need to do a concat to all dataframes who has same columns, then do merge to all resultant

Comment: you can check column by `if 'A' in df.columns:`